# Listing all devices on a network - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am trying to display all devices fro a network according to this tutorial: http://android-er.blogspot.ro/2015/12/lookup-manufacturer-info-by-mac-address.html but for no reason I get only the router Ip and Mac ... but (weird part).. when i scan with Fing (other android app) and after I scan with my app I get all the results..

My code from scanwifi.jar:

```
    package com.nliplace.nli.unealta;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class scanwifi extends AppCompatActivity {

        Button btnRead;
        TextView textResult;

        ListView listViewNode;
        ArrayList<Node> listNote;
        ArrayAdapter<Node> adapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanwifi);
            btnRead = (Button)findViewById(R.id.readclient);
            textResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

            listViewNode = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.nodelist);
            listNote = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayAdapter<Node> adapter =
                    new ArrayAdapter<Node>(
                            scanwifi.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                            listNote);
            listViewNode.setAdapter(adapter);

            listViewNode.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Node node = (Node) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
                    Toast.makeText(scanwifi.this,
                            "MAC:\t" + node.mac + "\n" +
                                    "IP:\t" + node.ip + "\n" +
                                    "company:\t" + node.company + "\n" +
                                    "country:\t" + node.country + "\n" +
                                    "addressL1:\t" + node.addressL1 + "\n" +
                                    "addressL2:\t" + node.addressL2 + "\n" +
                                    "addressL3:\t" + node.addressL3 + "\n" +
                                    "type:\t" + node.type + "\n" +
                                    "startHex:\t" + node.startHex + "\n" +
                                    "endHex:\t" + node.endHex + "\n" +
                                    "startDec:\t" + node.startDec + "\n" +
                                    "endDec:\t" + node.endDec,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            btnRead.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    new TaskReadAddresses(listNote, listViewNode).execute();
                }
            });
        }



        class Node {
            String ip;
            String mac;

            String jsonBody;
            String startHex;
            String endHex;
            String startDec;
            String endDec;
            String company;
            String addressL1;
            String addressL2;
            String addressL3;
            String country;
            String type;

            String remark;

            String queryString = "http://www.macvendorlookup.com/api/v2/";

            Node(String ip, String mac){
                this.ip = ip;
                this.mac = mac;
                queryMacVendorLookup();
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "IP: " + ip + "\n" + "MAC: " + mac + "\n" + company + "\n" + remark;
            }

            private String sendQuery(String qMac) throws IOException{
                String result = "";

                URL searchURL = new URL(queryString + qMac);

                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) searchURL.openConnection();

                if(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                            inputStreamReader,
                            8192);

                    String line = null;
                    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                        result += line;
                    }

                    bufferedReader.close();
                }

                return result;
            }


            private void ParseResult(String json){

                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(0);
                    startHex = jsonObject.getString("startHex");
                    endHex = jsonObject.getString("endHex");
                    startDec = jsonObject.getString("startDec");
                    endDec = jsonObject.getString("endDec");
                    company = jsonObject.getString("company");
                    addressL1 = jsonObject.getString("addressL1");
                    addressL2 = jsonObject.getString("addressL2");
                    addressL3 = jsonObject.getString("addressL3");
                    country = jsonObject.getString("country");
                    type = jsonObject.getString("type");
                    remark = "OK";

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    remark = e.getMessage();
                }

            }

            private void queryMacVendorLookup(){
                try {
                    jsonBody = sendQuery(mac);
                    ParseResult(jsonBody);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        private class TaskReadAddresses extends AsyncTask<Void, Node, Void> {

            ArrayList<Node> array;
            ListView listView;

            TaskReadAddresses(ArrayList<Node> array, ListView v){
                listView = v;
                this.array = array;
                array.clear();
                textResult.setText("querying...");
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                readAddresses();

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                textResult.setText("Done");
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Node... values) {
                listNote.add(values[0]);
                ((ArrayAdapter)(listView.getAdapter())).notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            private void readAddresses() {

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

                try {
                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));

                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        String[] splitted = line.split(" +");
                        if (splitted != null && splitted.length >= 4) {
                            String ip = splitted[0];
                            String mac = splitted[3];
                            if (mac.matches("..:..:..:..:..:..")) {
                                Node thisNode = new Node(ip, mac);
                                publishProgress(thisNode);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally{
                    try {
                        bufferedReader.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

My code from activity_scanwifi.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.nliplace.nli.unealta.scanwifi">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Aceasta activitate foloseste un API pentru a identifica dispozitive cunoscute."
        android:id="@+id/textView11" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/readclient"
        android:layout_width="156dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="Scaneaza"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/nodelist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: how i reappend the file /proc/net/arp? is ping enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To actually append in file /proc/net/arp you need to make a ping on the network.

Option 1: 
ping -b 192.168.0.255

Problem: You don't get windows divices becouse they deny Broadcast Ping.

Option 2: (recommended)

Ping all with for's.

Problem: will append the fille with all pinged ip and no mac (00:00:00:00:00:00) and you will have to deny all inalid mac's.

Comment: What is ping with fors? Is that for loops. I have similar problem in my app in which some devices don't respond to ping.. how can I accurately detect all host